# Remove decimals from values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that creates a report. The report is good but the values have decimals I don't want to see. Can anyone help me?

the query is as follows:

```
SELECT A.ItemCode, B.ItemName, A.OnHand,  a.WhsCode , a.MinOrder*b.NumInBuy as 'Minimum Voorraad'

FROM OITW A WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OITM B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.ItemCode = B.ItemCode
where b.ItemCode like '1%'  AND B.FrozenFor = 'N' And A.WhsCode ='KTC DV'  and ItmsGrpCod='112'
and  (a.MinOrder*b.NumInBuy) >= a.OnHand and a.MinOrder >0
```

And the report I get is this:

[image]

What do I do now to remove the decimals?
e.g. 5.000000 must be 5, and 5.00000000000 must be 5.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `cast`

```
select cast(235.415 as integer)
```

it will return 235

so in your case

```
    SELECT A.ItemCode, B.ItemName, cast(A.OnHand as integer),  a.WhsCode ,
cast( a.MinOrder*b.NumInBuy as integer) as 'Minimum Voorraad'    
    FROM OITW A WITH (NOLOCK) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OITM B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.ItemCode = B.ItemCode
    where b.ItemCode like '1%'  AND B.FrozenFor = 'N' And A.WhsCode ='KTC DV'  and ItmsGrpCod='112'
    and  (a.MinOrder*b.NumInBuy) >= a.OnHand and a.MinOrder >0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zaynul, It worked awesomely!

Comment: @Rivesh if it helps mark it as accepted answer